# MaterialUI/CSS create this box

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to make this component with MaterialUI:
[original box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Deoy.png)

How can I make this? I'm trying with the card component, but seems like:

[sh*tty box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofwE2.png)

This is my makeStyles:

```
  const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
    cardHeader: {
      color: "white",
      borderRadius: "0"
    },
    cardDescription: {
      display: "flex",
      justifyContent: "center",
      alignItems: "baseline",
      backgroundColor: "#315059",
      color: "cyan"
    },
  }));

  const classes = useStyles();
```

And this is my card component:

```
<Card style={{borderRadius: "0"}}>
          <CardHeader
            title="VELOCIDAD MEDIA"
            titleTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
            subheaderTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
            className={classes.cardHeader}
            style={{backgroundColor:"#f92f3b"}}
          />
          <CardContent style={{backgroundColor:"#f92f3b"}}>
            <div className={classes.cardDescription}>
              <Typography component="h2" variant="h3" color="cyan" >
                262
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="h6" color="white">
                KM/H
              </Typography>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
```

Comment: Thats not even material design, thats just styled content. Please post any code you have used and tried so we have something to start from (we're not a get-a-solution-for-free service). But this will be easier to achieve in CSS than dragging unrelated material design in.

Comment: @somethinghere edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your given code for sh*tty box and screenshot is not matching. Maybe other styles of the project are interfering with it. However, I made some changes to look similar to the required screenshot.

Note:- *Fonts and card dimensions depend on the use case*.

```
import { Card, CardContent, CardHeader, makeStyles, Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <Card style={{borderRadius: "0",width:'380px'}}>
          <CardHeader
            title="VELOCIDAD MEDIA"
            titleTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
            subheaderTypographyProps={{ align: "center" }}
            className={classes.cardHeader}
            style={{backgroundColor:"#f92f3b"}}
          />
          <CardContent style={{backgroundColor:"#f92f3b",padding:'8px'}}>
            <div className={classes.cardDescription}>
              <Typography component="h2" variant="h3" color="cyan" >
                262
              </Typography>
              <Typography variant="h6" style={{marginLeft:'15px', color:'#fff'}} color="white">
                KM/H
              </Typography>
            </div>
          </CardContent>
        </Card>
    </div>
  );
}


const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  cardHeader: {
    color: "white",
    borderRadius: "0",
  },
  cardDescription: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    backgroundColor: "#315059",
    color: "cyan",
    height:'150px'
  },
}));
```